# Find a previous date on a list closest to a specified date

Tags: vba, date, excel, excel-formula

I would like to have VBA code or formula that will take a variable date value and find it on a list range of dates. If it can't find the date I want it to find the closest previous date value.  `VLOOKUP` works great for finding an exact match but I am struggling with the code to find the closest previous date.

My only thought is to create a loop where if it doesn't match it continues to subtract a day from the variable  date until it can locate a match on the list.  That does not seem like the best or most efficient method and I hope someone can recommend a simpler solution.

Example:

```
Variable Date = 01/26/2014

Date List
02/04/2014
01/27/2014
01/24/2014
01/13/2014
12/29/2013

Desired Result = 01/24/2014
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could use [MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx) function with `match_type` parameter equal to 1: `If match_type is 1, MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value. Lookup_array must be placed in ascending order`

Comment: If it is ordered its easier to use lookup

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose your list of dates was in cells `A1:A5` and your check date was in cell `C1`, you could enter this function **ENTERED AS AN ARRAY FORMULA:**

```
=MAX(($A$1:$A$5<=C1)*A1:A5)
```

Rememeber, to enter it as an array formula, hit  <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>  + <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> + <kbd>`Enter`</kbd> when entering the formula.

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: @John Bustos - It may be too late to ask on this thread but I would like the formula to calculate through vba.  I tried 'prev_date = Application.Max((Date_Array <= Date_lookup) * Date_Array)' but receive a mismatch error.

Comment: @JohnW, In VBA, I'd just do a quick `for` loop and keep writing over the greatest `<=` variable until you run through the entire array... I think that would be the most efficient way... If you want, post another question and I'd give you the code if you can't work it out from my description....

Answer (score 3):

I went about this a little differently, no arrays needed
Find how many numbers are bigger then the one you are looking for with `CountIf()` 
Then I used `=Large` this will find the nth dates in a list we have the nth we are looking for in the `countIF()`

```
=LARGE(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,">="&TODAY()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup can do this actually, if you set the final argument to `true`, which looks for an approximate match. You need your dates sorted from Oldest to newest and it will return the first date that is not after your search term.